WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__args' in nltk
WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__args'

I have this error in Python nltk libray whenever i try to upload a document and try to find acronyms and English words from it (wordnet).
I tries reinstalling nltk libray. But still not working...

Please provide a minimum reproducible error and full error traceback.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
